# Create new type, or check type?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

For example, I have the below constructor:

```
function MyType(){

    this.someProp = 'someText';

};
```

I create a new instance:

```
var myVar = new MyType();
```

Now I want to check the type of this object...

```
console.log(typeof(myVar));    //object
console.log(myVar.toString()); //[object Object]
```

Is there any way for `typeof` or the default `toString` method to return **`MyType`**,  instead of just `object`.

- The above has been tested in Chrome console.
- JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/keqHN/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot override the behaviour of `typeof`. It's defined [in the spec](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.3) and there are a set number of possible return values. It uses the "[type](http://es5.github.com/#x8)" of the operand, which can only be one of null, undefined, string, boolean, number and object.

However, `instanceof` should work:

```
console.log(myVar instanceof MyType); // true
```

Side note... `typeof` is an operator, not a function, so you don't need the parentheses around it.

Comment: Is there anyway to return `MyType` as a string, rather than testing it against the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no custom types in Javascript. There are 9 native constructors:

- Number()
- String()
- Boolean()
- Object()
- Array()
- Function()
- Date()
- RegExp()
- Error()

There are also 3 primitive types:

- string
- number
- Boolean